# スクレイピングで5chの書き込みを取得したいができない

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

私は5chのアニメ実況が好きで、異なる2つの実況板の書き込みを取得し、時系列順に並べなおし、一つにまとめることを考えた。

ところが、hawk.5ch.netでの書き込みのスクレイピングができなかった。
なぜ取得できないか、どうすれば取得できるのか教えていただきたい。

例えば `himawari.5ch.net` のurlでコードを実行するとHTMLが表示されるが、

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://himawari.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livetx/1523962661/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

`hawk.5ch.net` のurlで実行するとエラーが起きた。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://hawk.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livejupiter/1523982845/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: 単に「エラーが出ます」だけではなく、具体的にどんなエラーが表示されたのかを質問に追記してください。

Answer (score 2):

`lxml` で行けました。あと文字化けについては、`response.encoding` の指定で直せます。

```
#res = requests.get('https://himawari.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livetx/1523962661/')
res = requests.get('https://hawk.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livejupiter/1523982845/')
res.encoding = res.apparent_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) を眺めてみると、[Installing a parser](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-a-parser) という項目があります。

> Another alternative is the pure-Python html5lib parser, which **parses HTML the way a web browser does**. Depending on your setup, you might install html5lib with one of these commands:
>
> $ apt-get install python-html5lib
>
> $ easy_install html5lib
>
> $ pip install html5lib

HTML parser を使いたい場合は、こちらの `html5lib` も選択肢の一つに入るでしょう。

```sh
$ lsb_release -ir
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    21.04

$ pip3 install html5lib
```

これで読み込むと問題は発生しません。なお、発生している問題は malformed な HTML テキスト(クローズタグがないなど)のパースを無制限に行っているためです。

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://hawk.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livejupiter/1523982845/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html5lib')

print(soup)
```

ここで `res.content` を指定しています。`res.text` はオリジナル・テキスト(エンコーディングはそのまま)ですが、`res.content` はバイト列になります。バイト列を指定して BeautifulSoup のインスタンスを初期化すると、内部で文字エンコーディングを推定して、`sys.getdefaultencoding()` で得られるエンコーディングへ自動的に変換してくれます。