# スクレイピングの文字化けを直したい

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://live23.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livetbs/1220170942/
このurlのレスをスクレイピングしたいのですが以下のコードですると文字化けします。

```
res=requests.get("https://live23.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livetbs/1220170942/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
threadRes=soup.find_all('dd')
print(threadRes) =>文字化けあり
```

また2行目の第一引数をres.contentにすると文字化けは直りますが全てのレスをスクレイピングできません
(このurlでは1001個のレスがあるのに対し223個のレスしか出力されない)

```
res=requests.get("https://live23.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livetbs/1220170942/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
print(soup)
threadRes=soup.find_all('dd')
print(len(threadRes)) => 223
```

どうすれば文字化けを直し全てのレスをスクレイピングできますか？

Comment: 重複候補: [スクレイピングで5chの書き込みを取得したいができない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/83520/3060) / [回答の一つ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/83520/3060) に文字化けへの対処方法も記載があります。

Answer (score 1):

手元の環境では質問コメントの[回答の一つ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/83520/3060)の通り、`res.encoding = res.apparent_encoding`を使っても文字化けしましたが、`res.encoding = "shift_jis"`で文字コードを直接指定することで正しく表示できることを確認しました。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://live23.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/livetbs/1220170942/")
#res.encoding = res.apparent_encoding
res.encoding = "shift_jis" 

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
threadRes=soup.find_all('dd')
print(threadRes)
print(len(threadRes))  # 1001
```

参考資料

- [Python3 – requestsの文字化け対策](http://memorandum-plus.com/2018/12/11/python3-requests%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96/)